# Being Frictionless, surface of contact

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I frequently hear references to a smooth surface, or frictionless pulley.
Can being frictionless be obtained if only one of the 2 surfaces has 0 coefficient of friction?
Or is it for the contact of those 2 surfaces (in friction due to material roughness)?

What in the cause of friction, molecular attraction or adhesion between materials?

Comment: -1. Please edit your comment to fix spelling errors and clarify the meaning of your question. You are in danger of being flagged.

Comment: I hope you know that the **coefficient of friction** is defined for a **pair** of surfaces and **not** a single surface.

Comment: but saying a block on smooth surface or frictionless pulley is confusing @harsh

Comment: By that they mean that the pair of surfaces in contact have zero coefficient of friction.

Comment: @harshit54 I think TheBoly raises an interesting point and I'm upvoting it. The Hyperphysics website states "Static frictional forces from the interlocking of the irregularities of two surfaces.." If one of the surfaces has no irregularities (the so called "smooth" surface) then there is nothing to "interlock" with. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: @CuriousFish Your thoughts?

Comment: @BobD You should post it as an answer. However the "interlocking" argument may be false sometimes. For example tires of F1 cars are "slick/smooth" and they provide the maximum amount of friction.

Comment: @harshit54 I didn't post it as an answer because I don't know the answer. You and I both know that friction is a complex topic and that most of what is modeled is experimentally based. We also know that two very smooth metal surfaces may stick together (so called cold weld). Trouble is many friction problem statements can lead one to think that you only need one smooth surface not to have friction. "A rope is on a frictionless pulley". "A block slides on a smooth table". And so on.

Comment: @BobD You are right. This is one of those question whose answer can vary from very simple to very advanced. I will upvote it.

Comment: But sticking of metal or rubber having much friction is a different(molecular attraction or adhesion) friction @harshit54

Comment: I know that coefficient of friction depends upon The two materials in contact and the nature of their surfaces. Coefficient of friction is defined like coefficient of rubber on plastic or coefficient of friction of rubber on steel.

Comment: @TheBroly You raise an interesting point about rubber.When we think of the surfaces involved with friction we tend to think of the materials as being non-deformable solids. Rubber's resistance to relative movement may also involve elastic deformation of the material. Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer your question.

> Can being frictionless be obtained if only one of the $2$ surfaces has $0$ **coefficient of friction**?

So if we consider two surfaces which are not adhesive in nature and do not deform, then yes, friction can be minimised by making only one of the surfaces smooth.

> What in the case of friction by molecular attraction or adhesion between materials?

In this case, there are many factors.

**Maximum** friction will be obtained if the contact area between the two surfaces is maximum. This would mean that you will want to make the two surfaces as smooth as possible. This fact is used in F1 car tyres.

So zero friction cannot be obtained in this case because this will only be possible if the two surfaces are not in contact.

Friction can however be minimized by decreasing the surface area in contact. For example treading of tires decreases the friction between the road and tire.

Comment: What about deformations or a plowing effect?surface roughness of materials only has a small effect on friction for most materials

Comment: molecular attraction or adhesion eg. rubber ,sticky materials and friction in  fluids

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not an answer. But frankly, I don’t think there is a simple answer. The very good, in my opinion, comments posted thus far confirm that friction is a complex topic. Although we try to use some simple models, one can always find examples where the model we use do not apply.

If we were faced with actually trying to determine a friction force involving two objects, we would probably have to resort to performing actual experiments involving the objects involved. Then we may be able to predict, within specific limits, what the friction force actually is.

In the meantime, the use of the admittedly oversimplified models can at least be useful in apply other physics concepts (e.g. determining friction work) on an academic level.

Hope this helps (but probably isn’t very satisfying). It was a very good  question.